# Can't connect to database with process.env variables but process.env vars print in log

Tags: node.js, express, environment-variables, amazon-redshift

I'm connecting to a redshift database with Node/express.  I put the variables to connect to the database in a .env file, and on my local machine, I'm able to connect to the website on localhost.

However, when I upload the files to the server and change the clientConfiguration, it no longer works, even after I've changed my require('dotenv').config({path: }) to the correct path.  I'm pretty sure the path is correct because process.env.HOST will print in the logs.

This error will show up:  password authentication failed for user "root"

This is the hardcoded part that works.

```
var clientConfiguration = {
   user: "user",
   database: "database",
   password: "password",
   port: 1234,
   host: "hosturl.com",
};
```

When I swap this part in, it no longer works.

```
 var clientConfiguration = {
   user: process.env.USER,
   database: process.env.DATABASE,
   password: process.env.PASSWORD,
   port: process.env.PORT,
   host: process.env.HOST,
 };
```

I thought it was because process.env variables get read in as strings, but that didn't help even after I used parseInt(process.env.PORT) -- I also didn't need the parseInt on my local machine, so I dont understand the

Comment: Do the values in your variables contain quotes? If not, perhaps you need to add quotes around the variables?

Comment: i have quotes for all my strings, but i have both double quotes and single quotes for some of them (one or the other)...

Answer (score 1):

Are you calling `dotenv.config()` as early as possible? I call it right after creating a new Express instance and it usually works.

Also, not sure if this is the 'accepted way', but I have had a similar issue before and found making an async `dotenv.config()` call inside the IIFE where I start my server solved the issue:

```js
//AWAIT DB CONNECTION BEFORE STARTING SERVER
(async function () {
  try {
    await dotenv.config();
    await connectDB();
    app.listen(PORT, ()=> {
      console.log(`Server listening in ${MODE} mode on ${PORT}`);
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(`Failure to start server: ${err}`);
  }
})();
```

`connectDB()` is my attempt to connect to a MongoDB database via `mongoose.connect()`. Obviously not the ideal solution as you want to call it earlier, but it did work.